# How to have a color show through a transparent image on Android?

Tags: android, view, transparent, alpha

What would be the simplest way to have a background color visible through the transparent parts of a gif/png in an Android view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set `android:background="_colorspec_"` in your layout.